# rendering a ReportLab pdf built from SimpleDocTemplate

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab

I've a got a django app that currently generates pdfs using a canvas that the user can download. I create a StringIO buffer, do some stuff and then send call response.write.

```
# Set up response
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=menu-%s.pdf' % str(menu_id)
# buffer
buff = StringIO()

# Create the pdf object
p = canvas.Canvas(buff)

# Add some elements... then

p.showPage()
p.save()

# Get the pdf from the buffer and return the response
pdf = buff.getvalue()
buff.close()
response.write(pdf)
```

I now want to build my pdf using platypus and SimpleDocTemplate and have written this

```
# Set up response
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
pdf_name = "menu-%s.pdf" % str(menu_id)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % pdf_name

menu_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_name, rightMargin=72,
                            leftMargin=72, topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)

# container for pdf elements
elements = []

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='centered', alignment=TA_CENTER))

# Add the content as before then...

menu_pdf.build(elements)
response.write(menu_pdf)
return response
```

But this doesn't work, it creates a bad pdf that cannot be opened. I presume the line

```
response.write(menu_pdf)
```

is incorrect.

How do I render the pdf?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your error is actually a pretty simple one.  It's just a matter of trying to write the wrong thing.  In your code, `menu_pdf` is not a PDF, but a `SimpleDocTemplate`, and the PDF has been stored in `pdf_name`, although here I suspect `pdf_name` is a path name rather than a file object.  To fix it, change your code to use a memory file like you did in your original code:

```
# Set up response
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
pdf_name = "menu-%s.pdf" % str(menu_id)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % pdf_name

buff = StringIO()

menu_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, rightMargin=72,
                            leftMargin=72, topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)

# container for pdf elements
elements = []

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='centered', alignment=TA_CENTER))

# Add the content as before then...

menu_pdf.build(elements)
response.write(buff.getvalue())
buff.close()
return response
```

I'm not sure if using file objects rather than paths with Platypus is mentioned in the documentation, but if you dig into the code you'll see that it is possible.

Comment: you probably want to use BytesIO instead of StringIO in Python3. But besides that, thanks for the great example.

Comment: I also used BytesIO instead of StringIO and not its working well, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For people who are working with python3 and django 1.7+ some changes to the answer need to be done.

```py
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
import io
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, BaseDocTemplate

def view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    doc = # ... create your SimpleDocTemplate / BaseDocTemplate
    # create the usual story
    story = []
    # ...
    doc.build(story)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=your_name.pdf'
    response.write(buffer.getvalue())
    buffer.close()

    return response
```